# Update Sqlite table values from VBA created array

Tags: sql, arrays, vba, sqlite, adodb

I'm trying to UPDATE a table column named "OrigMask" in myfile.sqlite by using an array created in my VBA code. I'm struggling with the syntax. The VBA array is named "NewMask" and has 864 elements as does the table "OrigMask".  How do I create the sql  statement in VBA and execute. Help is VERY much appreciated !

I'm establishing a statement & connection like so:

```vb
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 

Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

conn.Open "DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database=C:\myfile.sqlite;"

strSQL1 = "UPDATE MyTable SET OrigMask= NewMask;"

rst.Open strSQL1, conn
Set rst = Nothing: Set conn = Nothing
```

Comment: That's not really how SQL works.  What exactly are you hoping to achieve with your update?

Answer (score 0):

Several issues here:

1. You need to iterate through you array and not integrate whole object in SQL as *NewMask* is unrecognized identifier in database.
2. An update query is an action query and not a resultset to be retrieved in a recordset.
3. You need a `WHERE` clause in `UPDATE` or all records are update not row by row.

Therefore, consider a `For Each` loop through a parameterized ADO command object:

```vb
strSQL1 = "UPDATE MyTable SET OrigMask = ? WHERE id = ?;"
i = 1

For Each var In NewMask
    Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    With cmd
       .ActiveConnection = conn
       .CommandText = strSQL1
       .CommandType = adCmdText
       .CommandTimeout = 15
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("maskparam", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, var)
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("idparam", adInt, adParamInput, , i)
       .Execute
    End With

    i = i + 1
Next var
```